# How to undo killall5 -9 in linux

Tags: linux

I was trying to kill running process for an application hosted on my linux server and used `killall5 -9` now I am unable to login to my linux server. Can someone please guide how to recover

Comment: Sounds like you've killed the login process.  Try rebooting and think of the consequences before you use commands like killall.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to be able to "recover" from this situation is to physically reboot the server. Currently it is in kind of halt state with probably running only kernel and no processes at all. If this is enterprise grade server you can login in to the service console (iLO, iDRAC or similar) and from there reboot the server.

Will be wise if you are not sure what command do to read the manual and think about the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

You've killed essentially all running processes on the system. The `killall5` command is designed to be run only as part of a shutdown/reboot script, never manually.

The only way to recover is to reset the server: if it is a physical server and you don't have a hardware-based remote management solution, then someone must physically visit the server and press the reset button.

If it is a virtual server, there is probably some sort of a virtual server management interface (maybe a web GUI) you can use to remotely reset the server.